# Reproduce a JavaScript router login function in Java

Tags: javascript, java, hash, authentication

I'm trying to mimic a login function on a router login page. The function is included on the login page along with some utility JS scripts. Each time the page is loaded, a new salt is included and a hash is generated from the inputted password and the selected user (there are only two possibilities).

Here is the JavaScript login function:

```
function send_login() {
                var salt = "8106037b";
                var password = "";
                if (graphic_auth == "false") {
                    password = document.forms.myform.old_password.value.substr(0, 16);
                    document.forms.myform.old_password.value = "";
                    // Make sure password never gets sent as clear text
                } else {
                    password = document.forms.myform.new_password.value.substr(0, 16);
                    document.forms.myform.new_password.value = "";
                    // Make sure password never gets sent as clear text
                }
                for (var i = password.length; i < 16; i++) {
                    password += String.fromCharCode(1); // String.fromCharCode(1) = A
                }
                var input = salt + password;
                for (var i = input.length; i < 63; i++) {
                    input += String.fromCharCode(1);
                }
                if (graphic_auth == "false") {
                    input += (document.forms.myform.old_username.value == 'user') ? 'U' : String.fromCharCode(1);
                } else {
                    input += (document.forms.myform.new_username.value == 'user') ? 'U' : String.fromCharCode(1);
                }
                var hash = hex_md5(input);
                var login_hash = salt.concat(hash);
            }
```

And this is my attempt at reproducing it in Java:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
    try {
        engine.eval(new FileReader("C:/Users/xx/Documents/Fiddler2/Captures/md5.js"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    invocable = (Invocable) engine;

    System.out.print(generateLoginHash("8106037b", ""));
}

public static String generateLoginHash(String salt, String password) {
    for (int i = password.length(); i < 16; i++) {
        password += "A";
    }
    String input = salt+password;
    for (int i = input.length(); i < 63; i++) {
        input += "A";
    }
    // input += (document.forms.myform.old_username.value == 'user') ? 'U' : String.fromCharCode(1);
    input += "U";
    System.out.print(input + "\n");
    String hash = hash(input);
    String login_hash = salt + hash;
    return login_hash;
}

public static String hash(String input) {
    Object result = null;
    try {
        result = invocable.invokeFunction("hex_md5", input);
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

As you can see, I use the same JS MD5 implementation as is used by the login page (it is downloaded and saved).

However, my generated login hashes does not match the actual hashes generated by the login script.

For example, a login with User "user", blank password and salt 8106037b should result in hash: 8106037bb70f15dcbd74fd1a7b14df4f54483863, but mine does not match.

What have I missed?

The JavaScript MD5 implementation (for those interested):

```
/*
 * A JavaScript implementation of the RSA Data Security, Inc. MD5 Message
 * Digest Algorithm, as defined in RFC 1321.
 * Version 2.1 Copyright (C) Paul Johnston 1999 - 2002.
 * Other contributors: Greg Holt, Andrew Kepert, Ydnar, Lostinet
 * Distributed under the BSD License
 * See http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5 for more info.
 */

/*
 * Configurable variables. You may need to tweak these to be compatible with
 * the server-side, but the defaults work in most cases.
 */
var hexcase = 0;  /* hex output format. 0 - lowercase; 1 - uppercase        */
var b64pad  = ""; /* base-64 pad character. "=" for strict RFC compliance   */
var chrsz   = 8;  /* bits per input character. 8 - ASCII; 16 - Unicode      */

/*
 * These are the functions you'll usually want to call
 * They take string arguments and return either hex or base-64 encoded strings
 */
function hex_md5(s){ return binl2hex(core_md5(str2binl(s), s.length * chrsz));}
function b64_md5(s){ return binl2b64(core_md5(str2binl(s), s.length * chrsz));}
function str_md5(s){ return binl2str(core_md5(str2binl(s), s.length * chrsz));}
function hex_hmac_md5(key, data) { return binl2hex(core_hmac_md5(key, data)); }
function b64_hmac_md5(key, data) { return binl2b64(core_hmac_md5(key, data)); }
function str_hmac_md5(key, data) { return binl2str(core_hmac_md5(key, data)); }

/* 
 * Perform a simple self-test to see if the VM is working 
 */
function md5_vm_test()
{
  return hex_md5("abc") == "900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72";
}

/*
 * Calculate the MD5 of an array of little-endian words, and a bit length
 */
function core_md5(x, len)
{
  /* append padding */
  x[len >> 5] |= 0x80 << ((len) % 32);
  x[(((len + 64) >>> 9) << 4) + 14] = len;

  var a =  1732584193;
  var b = -271733879;
  var c = -1732584194;
  var d =  271733878;

  for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i += 16)
  {
    var olda = a;
    var oldb = b;
    var oldc = c;
    var oldd = d;

    a = md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 0], 7 , -680876936);
    d = md5_ff(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 1], 12, -389564586);
    c = md5_ff(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 2], 17,  606105819);
    b = md5_ff(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 3], 22, -1044525330);
    a = md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 4], 7 , -176418897);
    d = md5_ff(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 5], 12,  1200080426);
    c = md5_ff(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 6], 17, -1473231341);
    b = md5_ff(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 7], 22, -45705983);
    a = md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 8], 7 ,  1770035416);
    d = md5_ff(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 9], 12, -1958414417);
    c = md5_ff(c, d, a, b, x[i+10], 17, -42063);
    b = md5_ff(b, c, d, a, x[i+11], 22, -1990404162);
    a = md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x[i+12], 7 ,  1804603682);
    d = md5_ff(d, a, b, c, x[i+13], 12, -40341101);
    c = md5_ff(c, d, a, b, x[i+14], 17, -1502002290);
    b = md5_ff(b, c, d, a, x[i+15], 22,  1236535329);

    a = md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 1], 5 , -165796510);
    d = md5_gg(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 6], 9 , -1069501632);
    c = md5_gg(c, d, a, b, x[i+11], 14,  643717713);
    b = md5_gg(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 0], 20, -373897302);
    a = md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 5], 5 , -701558691);
    d = md5_gg(d, a, b, c, x[i+10], 9 ,  38016083);
    c = md5_gg(c, d, a, b, x[i+15], 14, -660478335);
    b = md5_gg(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 4], 20, -405537848);
    a = md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 9], 5 ,  568446438);
    d = md5_gg(d, a, b, c, x[i+14], 9 , -1019803690);
    c = md5_gg(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 3], 14, -187363961);
    b = md5_gg(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 8], 20,  1163531501);
    a = md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x[i+13], 5 , -1444681467);
    d = md5_gg(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 2], 9 , -51403784);
    c = md5_gg(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 7], 14,  1735328473);
    b = md5_gg(b, c, d, a, x[i+12], 20, -1926607734);

    a = md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 5], 4 , -378558);
    d = md5_hh(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 8], 11, -2022574463);
    c = md5_hh(c, d, a, b, x[i+11], 16,  1839030562);
    b = md5_hh(b, c, d, a, x[i+14], 23, -35309556);
    a = md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 1], 4 , -1530992060);
    d = md5_hh(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 4], 11,  1272893353);
    c = md5_hh(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 7], 16, -155497632);
    b = md5_hh(b, c, d, a, x[i+10], 23, -1094730640);
    a = md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x[i+13], 4 ,  681279174);
    d = md5_hh(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 0], 11, -358537222);
    c = md5_hh(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 3], 16, -722521979);
    b = md5_hh(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 6], 23,  76029189);
    a = md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 9], 4 , -640364487);
    d = md5_hh(d, a, b, c, x[i+12], 11, -421815835);
    c = md5_hh(c, d, a, b, x[i+15], 16,  530742520);
    b = md5_hh(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 2], 23, -995338651);

    a = md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 0], 6 , -198630844);
    d = md5_ii(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 7], 10,  1126891415);
    c = md5_ii(c, d, a, b, x[i+14], 15, -1416354905);
    b = md5_ii(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 5], 21, -57434055);
    a = md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x[i+12], 6 ,  1700485571);
    d = md5_ii(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 3], 10, -1894986606);
    c = md5_ii(c, d, a, b, x[i+10], 15, -1051523);
    b = md5_ii(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 1], 21, -2054922799);
    a = md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 8], 6 ,  1873313359);
    d = md5_ii(d, a, b, c, x[i+15], 10, -30611744);
    c = md5_ii(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 6], 15, -1560198380);
    b = md5_ii(b, c, d, a, x[i+13], 21,  1309151649);
    a = md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 4], 6 , -145523070);
    d = md5_ii(d, a, b, c, x[i+11], 10, -1120210379);
    c = md5_ii(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 2], 15,  718787259);
    b = md5_ii(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 9], 21, -343485551);

    a = safe_add(a, olda);
    b = safe_add(b, oldb);
    c = safe_add(c, oldc);
    d = safe_add(d, oldd);
  }
  return Array(a, b, c, d);

}

/*
 * These functions implement the four basic operations the algorithm uses.
 */
function md5_cmn(q, a, b, x, s, t)
{
  return safe_add(bit_rol(safe_add(safe_add(a, q), safe_add(x, t)), s),b);
}
function md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x, s, t)
{
  return md5_cmn((b & c) | ((~b) & d), a, b, x, s, t);
}
function md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x, s, t)
{
  return md5_cmn((b & d) | (c & (~d)), a, b, x, s, t);
}
function md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x, s, t)
{
  return md5_cmn(b ^ c ^ d, a, b, x, s, t);
}
function md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x, s, t)
{
  return md5_cmn(c ^ (b | (~d)), a, b, x, s, t);
}

/*
 * Calculate the HMAC-MD5, of a key and some data
 */
function core_hmac_md5(key, data)
{
  var bkey = str2binl(key);
  if(bkey.length > 16) bkey = core_md5(bkey, key.length * chrsz);

  var ipad = Array(16), opad = Array(16);
  for(var i = 0; i < 16; i++) 
  {
    ipad[i] = bkey[i] ^ 0x36363636;
    opad[i] = bkey[i] ^ 0x5C5C5C5C;
  }

  var hash = core_md5(ipad.concat(str2binl(data)), 512 + data.length * chrsz);
  return core_md5(opad.concat(hash), 512 + 128);
}

/*
 * Add integers, wrapping at 2^32. This uses 16-bit operations internally
 * to work around bugs in some JS interpreters.
 */
function safe_add(x, y)
{
  var lsw = (x & 0xFFFF) + (y & 0xFFFF);
  var msw = (x >> 16) + (y >> 16) + (lsw >> 16);
  return (msw << 16) | (lsw & 0xFFFF);
}

/*
 * Bitwise rotate a 32-bit number to the left.
 */
function bit_rol(num, cnt)
{
  return (num << cnt) | (num >>> (32 - cnt));
}

/*
 * Convert a string to an array of little-endian words
 * If chrsz is ASCII, characters >255 have their hi-byte silently ignored.
 */
function str2binl(str)
{
  var bin = Array();
  var mask = (1 << chrsz) - 1;
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length * chrsz; i += chrsz)
    bin[i>>5] |= (str.charCodeAt(i / chrsz) & mask) << (i%32);
  return bin;
}

/*
 * Convert an array of little-endian words to a string
 */
function binl2str(bin)
{
  var str = "";
  var mask = (1 << chrsz) - 1;
  for(var i = 0; i < bin.length * 32; i += chrsz)
    str += String.fromCharCode((bin[i>>5] >>> (i % 32)) & mask);
  return str;
}

/*
 * Convert an array of little-endian words to a hex string.
 */
function binl2hex(binarray)
{
  var hex_tab = hexcase ? "0123456789ABCDEF" : "0123456789abcdef";
  var str = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < binarray.length * 4; i++)
  {
    str += hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i>>2] >> ((i%4)*8+4)) & 0xF) +
           hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i>>2] >> ((i%4)*8  )) & 0xF);
  }
  return str;
}

/*
 * Convert an array of little-endian words to a base-64 string
 */
function binl2b64(binarray)
{
  var tab = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
  var str = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < binarray.length * 4; i += 3)
  {
    var triplet = (((binarray[i   >> 2] >> 8 * ( i   %4)) & 0xFF) << 16)
                | (((binarray[i+1 >> 2] >> 8 * ((i+1)%4)) & 0xFF) << 8 )
                |  ((binarray[i+2 >> 2] >> 8 * ((i+2)%4)) & 0xFF);
    for(var j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
      if(i * 8 + j * 6 > binarray.length * 32) str += b64pad;
      else str += tab.charAt((triplet >> 6*(3-j)) & 0x3F);
    }
  }
  return str;
}

function md5_js_loaded() { return true; }
```

The full page: https://gist.github.com/tsoernes/216d1794173496617e9d

Comment: `String.fromCharCode(1)` shouldn't be "A"...

Comment: Ah, so thats it. I pasted `window.alert(String.fromCharCode(1));` into an online JavaScript editor and got A out. Now I tried another one and got . I guess I have to use `Character.toChars(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.fromCharCode(1)` returns a string containing the character with code point 1. This is an invisible control character, it's definitely not "A" (which is 65).

Instead of `"A"`, use `"\u0001"`. (`\u0001` is an escape sequence for that character)